# What's an AoB (Array of Bytes)

Tags: c++, memory

I have encountered this term a couple of times now, and I have googled for explanations, but couldn't find any.

I'm accessing the memory of a running software-game. I do have an address but I'm also given an AoB, for example

> 89 8B ? ? 00 00 8B 50 ? 89 93 ? ?.

What do I do with it? 
I'd appreciate it if you could give me a guide or something.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array of bytes is best explained in C/++ as an array of `[unsigned] char`.
The values you see are only hexadecimal representations of these bytes or `unsigned char`'s.

Comment: Thanks, but that's the part I've already understood. I mean, what can I do with it? Like the one I gave. What does it tell me... It's not an address.

Comment: Then tell us what you want/need to do with it. Usually one would group 4 bytes to a bigger type like `int` or even to more complex data-structures like `struct`s.

Comment: Oh, so it's struct is not something fixed. Thanks, I'll ask for it's struct at the forum I found it.

Comment: I am not quite sure if you got me right there but asking for the structure is not a bad idea though ;)

Comment: Well I'm not sure either, but I did see  an example for its struct at one of the forums. But what do the '?' mean? A random byte or what?

Comment: It would be good to know the origin of this output (eg. which program did you use to obtain these values).

Comment: I don't know how did they find these... I'll have to ask there.

Answer (score 1):

An array of bytes is a contiguous series of values, usually in the range 0 to 255 (0x00 to 0xFF).

The contents must be interpreted by the programmer and can be anything from addresses to pixels for a bitmap.

A common use of `AoB`, a.k.a. buffer, is for I/O, reading and writing data.  The fundamental I/O routines do not care about content, just quantity, source and destination.  A program may read large amounts of data into an AOB, then later cast it as some kind of structure or assign fields with data from the buffer.  See also "serialization."  This is a performance technique with I/O: convert many small reads into one large block read.

Not all data has to be in structures or objects; those are just a convenience.

Comment: Thanks, I think Ive got it now.